# Does xCode have a debugging console for iOS development like a browser's console?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, console

I would like to easily check property values by typing them into the console (how it works in browser's console). It seems to not be possible. What are the alternatives for easy debugging of different property values instead of breakpoints?

Comment: the key thing missing from all the answers below is that your app needs to be stopped at a breakpoint before you can get property details for the view (if you pause the app you can work in from the application itself and find some things with a bit of digging...)

Comment: There is also the concept of "watchpoints" which might be more like what you want.  See the section called "Setting Watchpoints" at http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html.  They aren't well supported from the Xcode UI but are accessible from the debug area console.

Comment: Got it. Thanks everyone! Breakpoints + using the "po" command is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note also that breakpoints aren't just "stop" locations.  You can, for example, edit them so that something gets printed and then the program continues without your intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use breakpoints. there is no other options. breakpoints is something like `debugger` so put break point wherever you need and then when you reach at that breakpoint application will pause and If you simply take mouse curser over that line then also you can know the value of different properties.

you can use `po` command to print value of any property. write in console(beside `lldb`),
`po` then space and than property or variable name and you will get value of it.

You can use `step over` to go to next line and can use `continue execution` to continue through all breakpoints.

You can refer [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/28289/debugging-ios-apps-in-xcode-4-5). It is for old xcode but conceptually same with current.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Type 'po propertyname' into the console and click enter.

Comment: Into which console? Right now I only see the output consoles... and well it doesn't work in those.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in your code to pause it where you want. Then the debugger will start when the code reaches that point and you'll be able to do that on the same console as the output.

Answer (score 1):

In the console you can see the property values using po propertyName.
For view debugging, xcode provides view debugger [as this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F4Nm.png)

Comment: ah, I see. So you can do this only after setting a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Closest thing is the console where you can look at variables and there is an option to look at an exploded view of you UI, where the classes and properties can be inspected. This is activated when you are running your app and click on the button with a hover-text "Debug View Hiererachy". You can find this button just above the console, to the left of the location icon.

[image]